# Expansion of logic array to 2D array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In my system, each pixel on an LCD screen is represented by 16-bits (RGBA):

```
typedef logic [15:0] pix;
```

In order to display characters on the screen, I have created a simple 8x8 typeface, whereby characters are stored such as:

```
typedef logic char_8x8 [7:0][7:0];
localparam char_8x8 txt_G = '{'h3C, 'h66, 'h03, 'h03, 'h73, 'h66, 'h7C, 'h00};
```

As they are currently stored (the hex numbers above), a `'b1` represents a turned-on pixel and `'b0` turned off.

Now,  to display them, I need some method to convert each character to the following form:

```
typedef logic [15:0] char_8x8_colored [7:0][7:0];
```

Notice how now each pixel element also carries the 16 bits of color as a packed array. (Frankly I'm not 100% how the whole packed/unpacked affects code - even though I know the implementation difference).

The way this would work is, wherever there exists a `'b1` in the  character array, this would be replaced with an element with value `'hFFFF` (white) - and of course `'h0000` (black) for no pixel present.

I'm unsure of the best way to implement this in SystemVerilog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you the only type of indices you can use in systemverilog are slices (without stride). I know that numpy, pytorch, or octave for instance have much richer indexing options and could use something like `colored[face] = foreground`. To set the color of all the pixels turned on. But in systemverilog I would go with a function.

```verilog
function char_8x8_colored  color_out(
  input char_8x8 face, 
  input pix background, 
  input pix foreground);
char_8x8_colored data;
begin
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; i = i + 1) begin
      data[i][j] = face[i][j] ? foreground : background;
    end
   end
  end
end
endfunction
```

This is a pure function this function can be synthesized using without any logic (only routing) if you pass a parameter such as `txt_G` as the `face` argument.